# Anonymous Class results in Error; $var = New Class

Tags: php

```
$gen = NEW CLASS {

    public function Num() {

        $number = mt_rand('0','9');

            function Duplicate($number) {
                $number = $number.$number;
                return $number;
            }

        return Duplicate($number);
    }

}

echo $gen->Num();
```

When running the code above I get the following error:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in /home/user/domain/new.php on line 69`

Am I doing something wrong here?

---

And will this be backwards compatible with anything older than PHP 7?

Comment: You lack a semicolon before echo.

Comment: And `NEW CLASS` certainly is _not_ a valid class name.

Comment: @arkascha It seems you can now write `$a = new class {}` in PHP7, anonymous class... Cool :D http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php

Comment: @RaxWeber Thx, please post as an answer so could accept it.

Comment: @Justinas Thanks for the hint, that is indeed not familiar. But it makes sense for some cases I guess, especially together with the `extends` feature.

Comment: `will this be backwards compatible with anything older than PHP 7` No!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lack a semicolon before echo.